# Ace Editor generates CSS styles inside <head> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ace-editor

I found that when you are using Ace Editor (https://ace.c9.io/ or react-ace) inside the app, it generates CSS styles inside  tag.

It generates three  tags. One without id, and two others with 'ace_editor.css' and 'ace-tm' IDs.

Is there any way to prevent it, and force these styles being generated in another place?

[image: Styles]

Comment: It generates them in the `<head>` which is the only place a style tag is supposed to appear. So what is the problem?

Comment: @gforce301 The problem that it cause Web Accessibility issues, and I can't fix it. So, is there any chance to generate it into the file?

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "generate it into the file". What file? Which file? Where?

Comment: @gforce301 I do not these styles inside head <style> tag, I want them generated through the <link> and attached to the head

Comment: If those style rules, as you say, are causing "Web Accessibility issues" then it won't matter how they get into the page. Those type of issues are not caused by "how" the style rules are included but by "what" is in them.

Comment: Style tags can also appear within custom html elements created via shadow DOM.  In this case, Ace Editor doesn't work inside custom html elements because it puts its styles in the head tag instead of in the elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this without modifying the source code. It is unclear what do you mean by `Web Accessibility issues` but if it causes problems you should file a bug/feature request on ace issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I know its very long but am also facing the same issue @Remzes try to reset your window variable ace* and proceed. you don't want to create a link instead.